# Value error when reading data from Google Sheets with comma as decimal

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When reading from Google Sheet with Python and the Google API I have a hard time getting numeric values from the numeric values.

Where i live we use comma as decimal separator, which seems to be the problem.

The Google sheet input is:

[image]

with automatic format.

The Python script is:

```
gc = gspread.service_account(filename="gdocs_access.json")
sh = gc.open("my_file").worksheet("sheet 1")
data = sh.get_all_records(numericise_ignore=["all"])
print(data)

[{'id': 'b', 'value': '200,3'}, {'id': 'c', 'value': '40'}, {'id': 'a', 'value': '-30,5'}]
```

returning all numeric values as string.

If I put this in a df and convert the string values to int:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data['value'].astype(int)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '200,3'
```

Apparently this error is caused when passing a string representation of a float into int, but that does not help me much. It does not help me to first convert to float.

Is there a solution for this? I am sure I am not the first one using comma as decimal and trying to read Google sheets with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, when the values in the cells are the number values, how about using `value_render_option` as follows?

#### From:

```
data = sh.get_all_records(numericise_ignore=["all"])
```

#### To:

```
data = sh.get_all_records(numericise_ignore=["all"], value_render_option="UNFORMATTED_VALUE")
```

or

```
data = sh.get_all_records(value_render_option="UNFORMATTED_VALUE")
```

#### Reference:

- [get_all_records](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_all_records#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.get_all_records)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to change `,` to `.` in all of the strings. This can be done using the `str.replace`-method.

Either you can make a new list `data` using list comprehension and convert that to a DataFrame:

```
data = [{'id': e['id'], 'value': int(float(e['value'].replace(',', '.')))} for e in data]
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

or you can convert directly to a DataFrame and change the column.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data['value'] = data['value'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float).astype(int)
```